# CentOS 6 glibc Update issue

Tags: centos, glibc

my centOS version is centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64

I have executed the following commands to extract and install glibc-2.15

```
tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.14
mkdir build
cd build 
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14 
make -j4
make install
```

But when I check glib version with command `yum list glibc`, it shows:

> Installed Packages glibc.i686 2.12-1.192.el6 @base glibc.x86_64
>   2.12-1.192.el6 @base

Comment: What are the commands you have executed and what are the outputs to them?

Comment: cmds executed -  <br/> tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.14
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14
make -j4
make install  <br/> but glibc is still same version i.e. 2.12

Comment: Is it glibc2.14 or glibc2.15? Do you receive any error message when compiling? Are you checking the version of glibc under /opt or perhaps are you taking the version from your glibc called in your path?

Comment: It is glibc 2.15. No error while compiling. I am checking version by yum list glibc

Comment: Just edited your question with that relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

The version you get from `yum list glibc` is the glibc version found in your repos, not the one you have compiled manually.

If you want to make reference to the 2.15 version, you should check and use the glibc version from the folder in which you configured it when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

'Yum list glibc' will always show the glibc version which are available in the centos 6 repository.

The steps you've followed implies that you've build your own version of glibc but it doesn't mean it will change the version on repo as well.

If you're looking for the usage of upgraded libraries, then you must either export it or feed the upgraded libraries to the symbolic link under /lib/ or /lib64/ which can be done in the following ways.

1.`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

It will stay exposed until your current session gets logged out.

2. Replace the symbolic link
   `ln -sf /lib/glibc.so.6 /opt/glibc-2.14/glibc-2.14.so`

If any of your program stops working, then immediately execute below command.

`ln -sf /lib/glibc.so.6 glibc-2.x.so`

here x denotes your authentic version of glibc.